Ghusl delay after periods
Assalamu Alaikum. I am travelling and my periods ended today. It is not possible for me to perform ghusl until evening. What should I do? Should I perform the due Salats till evening as Qaza?

Why can't she perform ghusl? And what about tayammum? See https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/64973/

As I said, I am travelling. For example I am in a hospital right now, how can I perform ghusl? Basically, I don’t have the facilities or time to perform ghusl right now. Ghusl is a legislative process which should be done properly, its not like wudu that I can do it anywhere anytime. And can tayammum be a substitute for mandatory ghusl? Moreover, is it permissible for cases like this where water is available?

Time is often not a factor, prayer is most important so must make time for it. That you are 'traveling' is ambiguous - are you traveling on land or air? Can you not make a stop?  Are you not able to e.g. hire a hotel room or Airbnb or find a public shower or gym etc. and perform ghusl there? If there is any possible way to do ghusl then you must do ghusl. If there isn't then you can perform tayammum. Please research, and also read through the linked post.

By time, I meant time required to do ghusl. I am travelling with a group of people , I don’t think I should be an inconvenience to them and its not an option either. It is easy for you to say but I am not in a position to do ghusl at the moment. Now can I do tayammum when water is available and I will be able to do ghusl just after a few hours ?
